# Which is my correct ecutrho convergence?

Tags: quantum-espresso

[image]

For my 221MoS2 supercell, I fixed ecutwfc (60Ry) and k-points (441),

I used ultrasoft pseudopotential for my calculation. Which ecutrho value is correct because all are nearly similar.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the precision you need for your calculations.

One way...
From your data, if you are concerning only with energies with only one/two decimal places, your calculation are ok since the first value of ecutoff, 240 (as the first two decimal places remains the same for all other calculations). But if you are interested in energies with four decimal places, for example, the cutoff converged energy will be 420, as all the other results with greater ecutoff values remains with the same four decimal places.

Another way...
You can calculate a property you can measure and them, choose the corresponding value of ecutoff such the theoretical value has the same error as the experimental measurement.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer